# how to make this batch file color picker?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
echo.
echo (backgroundColor_textColor)
echo set color (Blue_White or Red_White)
echo.
set COLOR=
set /p COLOR = choose color from the color given: 
if "%COLOR%"=="blue_white" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="blue white" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="Blue_White" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="Blue White" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="BW" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="bw" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="red_white" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="red white" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="Red_White" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="Red White" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="RW" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="rw" goto rw

:bw
color 1f
goto start

:rw
color 4f

:start
pause
echo.
pause
```

Comment: In `set /p COLOR = choose color from the color given`: remove spaces surrounding `=`. There is defined variable `%COLOR %` (see trailing space) as currently written. And pay your attention to `/I` switch in `if /?`.

Comment: I flagged to close the post because we are unclear what you are asking - There isn't even a question to answer.

Comment: @SteveFest: Well, the question in the title could be answered this way: "Open a text editor, like Notepad, and type the commands"... **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini Very good! I love your comment!

Comment: @Aacini If I were brave enough, I would just type what you say into the answer box, and make it community wiki `:)`

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned in the comments, your problem is the spaces in the `set` command. It should look like this:

```
set /p COLOR=choose color from the color given:
```

Here is a "working" version of your script:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo (backgroundColor_textColor)
echo set color (Blue_White or Red_White)
echo.
set COLOR=
set /p COLOR=choose color from the color given:
if "%COLOR%"=="blue_white" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="blue white" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="Blue_White" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="Blue White" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="BW" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="bw" goto bw
if "%COLOR%"=="red_white" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="red white" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="Red_White" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="Red White" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="RW" goto rw
if "%COLOR%"=="rw" goto rw

:bw
color 1f
goto start

:rw
color 4f

:start
pause
echo.
pause
```

Comment: If possible, please added a little section of what Aacini said in his comments - `"SteveFest: Well, the question in the title could be answered this way: "Open a text editor, like Notepad, and type the commands"... ;)"`. lol

Comment: *Your reply literally made me laugh, but* `(I wish to say the following, but that's a little mean, you can choose to read it or not. The only question in the entire post is "how to make this batch file color picker?", so wouldn't it be open a notepad, ctrl+c the code, ctrl+v the code? :-/ )`

Comment: It took all of 30 seconds to run the batch, find the problem and figure out the expected result.  Another few to see the user has 1 rep, is a kid and determine that English isn't his first language.  I'd say it was worth the couple minutes I spent to try and help him.

Comment: Wow! You're such a nice person :)

Comment: I see, it seems like you don't change any in my Command Line... BTW everything is okay now thanks :)